# Android Setting XY has moved from xyz to xyz to be seen in the Log

Tags: android

With the following code I am getting log entries that warn about the settings being used

```
  final int result;
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
     result = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS);
  } else { // OS < 17
      result = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS);
  }
```

The log entry says: Setting install_non_market_apps has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global

I tried calling the deprecated line in a separate method but it didn't help. Why would I see this log if the statements are inside an **if** ? Is there a better way to do what I'm doing or a way to avoid the log entry?

Comment: Are you sure the correct `getInt` is called? Place a breakpoint in both places and see which one is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change class that you call the `getInt()` on as well. Like this:

```
result = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS);
```

Calling `getInt()` on the `Secure` class [will always produce the warning message](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#L2750).

Comment: oh, that worked! hm, but it's strange that I get the right result with my aproach anyway, despite the log entry

Comment: If you look at the code I provided the link for, it will simply reroute your call to the correct `getInt()` implementation on the `Global` class.